# Get an overview of the fonts used in a .psd (including weight and italics) so I can optimize my webfont import and exclude unused variations?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, web-fonts, font-weight

When converting a psd to web, it can be tedious to figure out which variations of the font that I'll need to include as a webfont. Currently I just take note of the font as I come across it, but it'd be ideal if there was a script of some sort that would just list the variations required.

Comment: Check out this relevant thread on superuser [Find all the fonts used in a Photoshop file](http://superuser.com/questions/268785/find-all-the-fonts-used-in-a-photoshop-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [**List Fonts**](https://github.com/iamdarrenhall/list-fonts) script

> A very basic PhotoShop script to list all fonts used in the currently open and active PSD. The script looks at all text layers, and will also find multiple fonts from the same text layer. The results are shown in a dialog box, the contents of which can be selected, copied and pasted.

There are also more extensive tools to help with getting specs from your Photoshop files, useful when handing files over to developers (or when developing from your own Photoshop files):

[**specKing**](http://wuwacorp.com/specking/)

> specKing is a Photoshop plugin that provides tools to generate design specs and annotations

[**Ink**](http://ink.chrometaphore.com/)

> Ink is a plugin that helps you providing few extra important informations about your mockups by documenting your layers, from typography to effects and shape sizes.

*I have not used any of these myself so can't attest for their quality or suitability*

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for an overview of just the font names [this link](https://superuser.com/questions/268785/find-all-the-fonts-used-in-a-photoshop-file/357066) was helpful. Also I tried specKing above and found it helpful as quick detail info for specific text-layers